# The common roots of equation $ z^3+(1+i)z^2+(1+i)z+i=0 \text{ and } z^{1993}+z^{1994}+1=0 $

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to complex numbers, I need to find out the common roots of these two equations.

$$ z^3+(1+i)z^2+(1+i)z+i=0 $$
 and
$$ z^{1993}+z^{1994}+1=0 $$

Where $ i^2 = -1 $

I can't figure out any way to do this. What should be the good way to figure out?

Comment: You can easily verify that $\omega, \omega^2$ are common roots where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity. You only need to check about the third root of the cubic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$z^3+(1+i)z^2+(1+i)z+i = 0$$ $$\implies z^2(z+i) +z(z+i)+(z+i)=0$$ $$\implies (z+i)(z^2+z+1)=0$$ $$\text{ Roots are } z = -i, \omega, \omega^2$$

Now, if we substitute these roots into the expression: $z^{1993}+z^{1994}+1$, we find that the **solutions are** $\omega, \omega^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$z^3+(1+i)z^2+(1+i)z+i=(z+i)(z^2+z+1)=(z+i)(z-\omega)(z-\omega^2)$ where $\omega=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ is the cuberoot of unity. [Note that $z^3-1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=(z-1)(z-\omega)(z-\omega^2)$]. So the roots of the cubic equation are $-i,\omega,\omega^2$. Check which of these satisfy the second equation, keeping in mind the relations $\omega^3=1, 1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.